# thresholding using python using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

this is the code of threshold 
and i am getting error of "unexpected character after line continuation character"
plz help

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\ cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

titles = ['Original Image', 'Global Thresholding (v = 127)','Adaptive Mean Thresholding', 'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding']

images = [img, th1, th2, th3]
for i in xrange(4):
plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
plt.title(titles[i])
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()``
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\` from your code. code should be like this:

```
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
```

Your code worked for me without `\` char and after some indentation

Comment: still getting error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ouroo_000\Desktop\123\treshold.py", line 10, in <module>
    th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:949: error: (-215) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function cv::Mat::locateROI